# Ethics of posting if you're a bad programmer

Tags: discussion, policy, answers, asking-questions

I'm not a great (or, really, that good of a) programmer, but I enjoy reading other people's challenges, and thought I'd try my hand at submitting a few challenges myself. However, I don't see myself ever answering (m)any questions (Python isn't that exciting a language to golf). An obvious solution is to learn one of the more entertaining esolangs, but as a senior in high school, that's not something I have a lot of time for. Is it still ok for me to post questions without answering any?

Comment: I only ever golf in Python and Java (and the one oddball C# answer). I enjoy it. Doing the same thing with shorter syntax is no more or less entertaining - it is just another way to golf.

Comment: Post as many questions as you want. no need to worry about answering any. FYI I very rarely actually solve my own challenges. As long as I can visualize a definite solution method then I feel comfortable posting.

Comment: Since when is Python not exciting to golf? I enjoy it, and it's the language the majority of my answers are in. If you still say no, though, maybe you should try learning one of the languages you *don't* know that you think looks interesting. That can be fun as well. Try learning [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) for fun.

Comment: @mbomb007 I suppose it's better to say that it's not as fun because I'm not particularly *good* at it. I wish I had time to learn something like ><> or BF, but I won't at least until my college apps are done.

Comment: @Eridan BF is one of the easiest languages to learn what all the commands do (there are only 8 commands). It's knowing how to combine them for things like comparing numbers or other more complex things that are difficult. Golfing BF is harder, too.

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat as you. I have one well received answer but only because it was funny and 3-4 answers in the 0-1 vote range. But I've got a bunch of challenges I've posted and I have a lot of fun making them.

Answer (score 33):

## Of course you can!

We welcome any and all participation. How you choose to participate is up to you.

I went over a year without posting any challenges at all; all of my participation was answers. [Calvin's Hobbies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/26997), one of our most successful challenge authors, almost exclusively posts challenges. At least in my mind, the point of this community is to have fun. Do whatever you have the most fun doing!

A great way to grow your programming skills is to participate in challenges but there's nothing that says you have to.

As a challenge author, the greatest tool available to you is the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1). There you can get meaningful feedback about your challenges before they go live.

Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Is this just a way of calling me a bad programmer >;D

Comment: More seriously, I almost never use the Sandbox. Not sure what that implies about me or it.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I think you're the exception when it comes to the Sandbox.

Comment: @AlexA. I have [long been known to be anti-sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1305/3808) as well. :P

Comment: @Doorknob The perfect replacement for the sandbox is a separate review queue (accessible by all users), where one can view suggested questions one by one and leave constructive criticism (maybe even disable voting in the queue).

Answer (score 7):

## Of course you should!

We need challenges more than answers. I'd like to have more of Calvin's Hobbies in the community. Just keep in mind that a good challenge is more difficult than a good answer.